# Using dependency relationship to model database tables

Tags: database-design, uml, data-modeling

I am working on a project for which the data architect left some UML diagrams that describes the table's relationships I understand what association mean in term of class diagram.
But what does it mean in terms of table modelling?

[image]

Comment: What does "what does it mean in terms of table modelling" mean? What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/why you are 1st stuck in what published presentation of what design method? [ask] [Help] Asking for tutorials or book-length answers is off-topic.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 3):

**The first example** is about dependency between classes. The text below the picture explains very well why a dependency is used, although nothing in the diagram itself allows to draw this conclusion (missing operations on the `Cart`): the cart has an `add()` operation to add `Products`; so even if the cart is not directly associated with products (e.g. probably the cart has item and the items are associate with the product), it needs to know about the `Product` to perform all its operations (e.g. create the items and link them to products).

**The second example** is ambiguous: in UML you are not supposed to create a compartment per column. Then it is not clear if the dependency is between tables or between columns (I assume table from the graphic layout, but the compartments confuse me):

- First possibility: the architect wants to draw attention that the definition of the columns in the first table are dependent of the definition of the second table. For example if you change a column `Description` that would be a string in the UML but a `CHAR(20)` in the implementation to a `CHAR(40)`, you’d need to check all the tables that are dependent on it, to see if you would’t need to extend the size of the string as well.
- Second possibility: the architect wants to say that one column is dependent on another to reflect a database constraint (e.g a foreign key constraint). This would be an inappropriate use of the dependency. It’s not completely wrong, but would miss the fact that there would be an association between the two tables (a “relationship” in database modeling).

**Unrelated remark**: usually, when modeling an ORM the design models are independent of the implementation technology (e.g. whether you implement everything in Java, or some parts in SQL, a Cart is still a cart related tonproducts). When models are refined/detailed to show implementation details and in particular mapping of classes to database tables, a common practice is to use some stereotype that allow to identify the role of the class in your model (e.g. `«table»` like [here](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html))